# Java introspection/reflection copy beans

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, introspection

I'm writing a common method which copies two different types of beans which have common fields. I'm using introspection to get the write and read methods, like

```
propertyDescriptor1.getWriteMethod().invoke(bean1, propertyDescriptor2.getReadMethod().invoke(bean2) )
```

The above works fine for Strings, but fails for any primitive types like int,long.... 
Any elegant solutions to copying two different types of beans?

Edit: It's solved, the problem was not with primitive types, I was not checking if the propertyDescriptor.getName() was not "class"

Answer (score 4):

Why not use Apache Commons [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html).

It has a very useful method called `copyProperties` which copies properties from one bean to another if they share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which converts to a String and a function converts from a String to any type.  Using a combination of these two you can convert from just about any scalar type to any other.

If you need to convert collections, that is a little harder because you may need to convert the contents. e.g. List<integer> to List<Double>

How flexible to do you need the conversion to be?

Answer (score 0):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) is a powerful bean mapper that can cope with nested beans, collections, and all the other stuff you'll come across if you roll your own... might be worth checking out if your beans are complex.